# JavaFx 2.0 with Apache Pivot 2.0

Tags: apache, javafx

Is there a way the two (JavaFx & Apache Pivot) can inter operate  within the same application?
That is, can I add a Pivot "Component" on a JavaFx "Stage" or add a JavaFx "Node" on a Pivot "Window" ? The reason for doing so would be to leverage the best features of both frameworks.
I saw a project called pivot-fx (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/pivot-fx/) but it doesn't have any documentation, archives or demos.
I'd like to hear if anybody has attempted (or thought) of doing so. 
Any advice would be appreciated.